Modifiy laravel first page url
I try to modify first page of laravel pagination from /category/german-language?page=1 to /category/german-language
also how to edit backend api path to frontend path
Current JSON
{ "first_page_url": "http://backend.example.com/api/category/slug/german-language?page=1",
            "from": 1,
            "next_page_url": "http://backend.example.com/api/category/slug/german-language?page=2",
            "path": "http://backend.example.com/api/category/slug/german-language",
            "per_page": "25",
            "prev_page_url": null,
            "to": 25}

Expected JSON
{
 "first_page_url": "http://frontend.example.com/category/german-language",
            "from": 1,
            "next_page_url": "http://frontend.example.com/category/slug/german-language?page=2",
            "path": "http://frontend.example.com/category/german-language",
            "per_page": "25",
            "prev_page_url": null,
            "to": 25}


Your questions is not clear,  can you elaborate what actually you want to do?

"first_page_url": "http://backend.example.com/api/category/slug/german-language?page=1", changes to "first_page_url": "http://backend.example.com/api/category/slug/german-language",

I have posted my answer ,please check and let me know your feedback.

Using withPath() method you can modify the pagination URLs and as well as remove the ?page=1 . Lets assume you have $data as a paginator instance like this.
$data = Model::paginate(25); //$data is a paginator instance
$data->withPath(str_replace('?page=1', '', $data->url(1))); // $data->url(page_number) returns the URL for a given page number
....//Do other job and return $data//...

For more information on pagination instance(in this case $data) check the link here.
